# Discord.js bot seems to be doing nothing at all. Not even errors are appearing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I made a bot a while ago that was working perfectly fine. I haven't used it in a couple of months and now I tried starting again because I needed it, and its literally not doing anything. It always worked, didn't change anything, It's not even showing any errors. Can anyone help?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Intents } = Discord;
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] 
  })

require('dotenv').config();
var token = process.env.TOKEN;
 
const prefix = ';';
 
const fs = require('fs');
const { ClientRequest } = require('http');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is aan het opstarten...!');

    client.user.setActivity("Bot testing", {
        type: "PLAYING",
      });
});

//-------------
//Commands
//------------- 
client.on('messageCreate', message =>{

    if(message.content != '')
    {
        client.commands.get('suggest').execute(message, Discord)
    }

    if(message.content != '')
    {
        client.commands.get('nieuws').execute(message, Discord)
    }

    if(message.content != '')
    {
        client.commands.get('sollicitaties').execute(message, Discord)
    }

    if(message.content != '')
    {
        client.commands.get('regels').execute(message, Discord)
    }



    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: You may need to upgrade your discord.js version, discord recently deprecated a lot of old API functions. Also make sure you have the message contents intent enabled, it's required now if you want to read the content of a message.

Comment: It not seems too old. discord.js v13 should work fine for a while.

Comment: Tested your code on discord.js v13.11 and node.js v16.15.1: works fine, as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord recently started privileged intents. make sure you have enabled `message content intent` in your application's bot section. This will allow your bot to have access to reading message and its content. [More info](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055)

Comment: Discord will probably tell you if you requested intents you don't have at all.